I am having issues in Graphql query cannot query field slug on type Frontmatter
ERROR #85923  GRAPHQL.VALIDATION
There was an error in your GraphQL query:
Cannot query field "slug" on type "Frontmatter".
If you don't expect "slug" to exist on the type "Frontmatter" it is most likely a typo. However, if you expect "slug" to exist there are a couple of solutions
to common problems:

If you added a new data source and/or changed something inside gatsby-node/gatsby-config, please try a restart of your development server.
You want to optionally use your field "slug" and right now it is not used anywhere.

It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields.
File: node_modules/gatsby-redirect-from/gatsby-node.js:44:15
See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/creating-type-definitions
This is the error I am facing while executing gatsby build.

Please share a code example not just the error.
